# efficient way of looping through second argument of tuple for a condition and returning first argument of tuple

Tags: python, loops, tuples

**my_list**

```
[('cat', 1), ('dog', 2), ('cat', 2)]
```

I want to loop through the second argument (the integers) of the tuples in my_list to see it any of them is equal to say value = 1 and if so, return the first argument of the tuple containing value = 1.

```
    from operator import itemgetter
    for a in map(itemgetter(1), my_list):
        if a == 1:
            idx = map(itemgetter(1),my_list).index(a)  
            print map(itemgetter(0),my_list)[idx]
            #cat
```

Is there a more efifcient way to do the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result = [ x for x,y in my_list if y==1 ]
```

Comment: You're right @juanpa.arrivillaga and Moses Koledoye , I just updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to `map(itemgetter(1), ...)`, instead, *unpack the tuple*:

```
>>> data = [('cat', 1), ('dog', 2), ('cat', 2)]
>>> for animal, num in data:
...     if num == 1:
...         print(animal)
...
cat
>>>
```

Honestly, you don't even need unpacking. You can just work with the tuple directly by *indexing* it:

```
>>> for t in data:
...     if t[1] == 1:
...         print(t[0])
...
cat
>>>
```

You are over-engineering it with `itemgetter`. It's not necessary.

With regards to unpacking, you can do this with tuples anywhere:

```
>>> t = ('first', 'second')
>>> f, s = t
>>> f
'first'
>>> s
'second'
>>>
```

Or really with any iterable:

```
>>> a, b = [1,2]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>>
```

Although in some cases it really isn't advisable:

```
>>> a, b = {'a':2, 'b':1} # order will not be guaranteed!
>>> a
'b'
>>> b
'a'
>>>
```